# Why does TortoiseSVN show icon overlays on the folders but not on the files

Tags: tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN seemed to be slowing down my Windows Explorer a whole lot.  So I scouted around and was reminded (via google) that there is a feature available via the TortoiseSVN Settings dialog where you can exclude certain paths from the Icon Overlay treatment.

So I excluded the whole of the D: drive (by putting the line D:* in the "Exclude paths:" area), and then included back my working folder (by putting D:\Petert\PWC* into "Include paths").

But now what happens is that the folders in my working folder get the Tortoise overlays, but not the files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it so happens that my folder is called " D:\Peter\PWC " - notice that I had accidentally included an extra "t", as in "Petert", in this folder name in the excluded paths as described in my question!

After correcting the typo in the "Exclude paths" text box - voila, my files also get the Tortoise icon overlays.

It seems to indicate something else: i.e. that if you exclude a folder and its subfolders from Tortoise's icon overlay feature, it will nonetheless flag any versioned folders.  Which I suppose is quite helpful and probably doesn't take up too much time, etc., and anyway warns you that you have versioned files there which you might like to include via the "Include paths" in the Settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Look at TortoiseSVN documentation. It says you may have problems with overloaded images if there are too many ovreloaded images installed in your system by other software.

Comment: Thanks, Veton - as you can see from my own answer, it was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

This is the setting ["Show excluded folders as normal"](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-overlay) in action. That setting, if active, shows the 'normal' overlay for versioned folders, but since the folder(s) are excluded the status isn't fetched but only the normal overlay is shown instead. This is for performance reasons: it's much much faster to just check for an .svn folder than to fetch the whole status. But people still want to see whether a folder is versioned or not - that's why that option exists.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the problem you were having, but I was finding the overlays were not on the files either and folder overlays seemed to always been green ticked.  I found the setting under overalys to include network drives (my respositories were on network drives) and suddenly all the overlays started appearing for everything.